# How to set property to req.session

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, session

I am newby in node.js and sessions and I have problem is setting properties to sesssion ! I try to add property to session and save it in db but I get error

here is my codes : 
app.js : ( main js file )

```
const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri : 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/OnLineShop',
    collection : 'session'
})

// routes :
app.use(shopRoutes)
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes)
app.use(authroutes)


// session : 
app.use(session(
    {
        secret : 'secret key' , 
        resave : false , 
        saveUninitialized : false , 
        store : store
    }
))
```

and here is my authentication handler I named it auth.js :

```
 // rout handler for post login requst : 
    module.exports.postLogin = (req , res)=>{
        // session : 
        req.session.isLoggedIn = true 
        res.redirect('/')
    }
```

after I lunch this app and want to login this error appear :

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'isLoggedIn' of undefined
    at module.exports.postLogin (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/controllers/auth.js:15:28)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/nodejs_frontCast/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/nodejs_frontCast/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/sadra/Desktop/projects/web/javascript/shop-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
```

I don`t know how we can set property for session in right way !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve the issue please change the order of your code from,

```
// routes :
app.use(shopRoutes)
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes)
app.use(authroutes)


// session : 
app.use(session(
    {
        secret : 'secret key' , 
        resave : false , 
        saveUninitialized : false , 
        store : strore
    }
))
```

to

```
// session : 
app.use(session(
    {
        secret : 'secret key' , 
        resave : false , 
        saveUninitialized : false , 
        store : strore
    }
))

// routes :
app.use(shopRoutes)
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes)
app.use(authroutes)
```